# sklearn LogisticRegression: does it use multiple background threads?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have code that uses [sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) and [sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html). Everything else staying the same in the code, running the code using a multiprocess pool launches hundreds of threads in the logistic regression path, therefore completely hampering performance - htop screenshots for 36 processors:

Idle:

[image]

Forests (one processor stays idle as expected):

[image]

Logistic (all processors at 100%):

[image]

So is logistic regression spawning background threads (yes) and if yes is there a way to prevent that?

```
$ python3.6
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
>>> sklearn.__version__
'0.20.1'
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#why-does-my-job-use-more-cores-than-specified-with-n-jobs-under-osx-or-linux

Comment: Thanks, @VivekKumar this qualifies for an answer - adding some hint on how I can specify which library is doing it would be grand

Comment: Although i am still not sure why RandomForests don't use any of it

Comment: Cant say for sure. But it maybe related to the fact pointed by @ChuckIvan that LR internally uses liblinear which may have different implementation whereas RandomForests are developed by sklearn so have that point covered.

Answer (score 1):

While instantiating `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` you can always pass the number of threads to use via `n_jobs=N` where `N` is the desired number of threads. I would check if running it with `n_jobs=1` does not help. Otherwise, Python may be misreading the number of available threads in your environment. To ensure it does this well I would check.

```
import multiprocessing
print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
```

Under the hood `LogisticRegression` uses `sklearn.externals.joblib.Parallel` which does the threading. Its logic is rather complex so without intricate knowledge of your environment setup it would be hard to tell what it exactly does.

Comment: I have `n_jobs` set to 1 explicitly in both the forest and the regression init calls and I use `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` to set the pool size - it works correctly. `n_jobs` would spawn processes i am talking about threads here

Comment: I am sorry, I had misunderstood you. Then my answer is of no use here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this happens when you're fitting the model, check out this part of the model's fit() method source code ([link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/55bf5d9/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py#L998)):

```
    # The SAG solver releases the GIL so it's more efficient to use
    # threads for this solver.
    if solver in ['sag', 'saga']:
        prefer = 'threads'
    else:
        prefer = 'processes'
    fold_coefs_ = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, verbose=self.verbose,
                           **_joblib_parallel_args(prefer=prefer))(
        path_func(X, y, pos_class=class_, Cs=[self.C],
                  fit_intercept=self.fit_intercept, tol=self.tol,
                  verbose=self.verbose, solver=solver,
                  multi_class=multi_class, max_iter=self.max_iter,
                  class_weight=self.class_weight, check_input=False,
                  random_state=self.random_state, coef=warm_start_coef_,
                  penalty=self.penalty,
                  max_squared_sum=max_squared_sum,
                  sample_weight=sample_weight)
        for class_, warm_start_coef_ in zip(classes_, warm_start_coef))
```

keenly the situation

```
prefer = 'threads'
**_joblib_parallel_args(prefer=prefer)
```

It looks like if you're using the `sag` or `saga` solvers you could run into threading issues. But the default solver is `liblinear`.

Also, from the source for Parallel() used above ([link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/55bf5d93e5674f13a1134d93a11fd0cd11aabcd1/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py)), sklearn has this to say about a possible workaround for threading issues:

> ```
> 'threading' is a low-overhead alternative that is most efficient for
> functions that release the Global Interpreter Lock: e.g. I/O-bound code or
> CPU-bound code in a few calls to native code that explicitly releases the
> GIL.
> In addition, if the `dask` and `distributed` Python packages are installed,
> it is possible to use the 'dask' backend for better scheduling of nested
> parallel calls without over-subscription and potentially distribute
> parallel calls over a networked cluster of several hosts.
> ```

From my understanding something like the following can reduce threading:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


...
# create local cluster
client = Client(processes=False)             
model = LogisticRegression()
with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
    model.fit(...)
...
```

Leveraging [Dask Joblib](http://ml.dask.org/joblib.html) as suggested.

Comment: I'm not using `sag` or `saga`. Even if I were, would there be a way to stop skleran from spawning those threads?

Comment: I am not sure if the thread-spawning code is not actually in the library that actually calculates the regression (`sklearn` is only an interface to it).